# group by two columns and get unique column values in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to get the unique values per `name1` and `name2` of column `prod` into a further column `all_prods`. If I just group by one column (for example `name1`) then I know how to do it but how does it work if I want to group by two columns (`name1` and `name2`)?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name1':['x','x','x','z','z'],'name2':['x','x','x','z','z'],'prod':['c','c','f','f','f']})

df.assign(**{'all_prods': df.name1.map(df.groupby('name1')['prod'].unique())})
```

Comment: how to group by two columns: `df.groupby(['name1','name2'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `transform`

```
df['all_prods'] = df.groupby(['name1','name2'])['prod'].transform(lambda x : len(x)* [x.unique()])
df
Out[6]: 
  name1 name2 prod all_prods
0     x     x    c    [c, f]
1     x     x    c    [c, f]
2     x     x    f    [c, f]
3     z     z    f       [f]
4     z     z    f       [f]
```

Answer (score 0):

Variant of your original approach:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['name1', 'name2'], as_index=False)
           .agg(all_prods=('prod', lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))))
```

output:

```
  name1 name2 prod all_prods
0     x     x    c    [c, f]
1     x     x    c    [c, f]
2     x     x    f    [c, f]
3     z     z    f       [f]
4     z     z    f       [f]
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it:

```
df.merge(df.groupby(['name1', 'name2'])['prod'].apply(lambda x: x.unique()).reset_index(name='all_prods'), on=['name1', 'name2'], how='left')

#

    name1   name2   prod    all_prods
0   x       x       c       [c, f]
1   x       x       c       [c, f]
2   x       x       f       [c, f]
3   z       z       f       [f]
4   z       z       f       [f]
```